# AngularJs: Add class based on Model

Tags: json, angularjs

Just trying to apply a class if something is true. The documentation is very brief on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

Trying to add a class of `favorite` on the `li` if `1 === true`

Here's my Mock Object

```
    $scope.restaurantListFromSearch = [
        {restaurantName: "Zocala",
        details: {
            image: "http://placehold.it/124x78",
            url: "#",
            cuisineType: ["Sandwiches", "American", "BBQ"],
            description: "Modern, healthy, awesome BBW",
            priceRange: "$",
            userFavorite: 0
        }},
        {restaurantName: "Subway",
        details: {
            image: "http://placehold.it/124x78",
            url: "#",
            cuisineType: ["Sandwiches", "American", "BBQ"],
            description: "Modern, healthy, awesome BBW",
            priceRange: "$",
            userFavorite: 1
        }},
        {restaurantName: "Hungry Howies",
        details: {
            image: "http://placehold.it/124x78",
            url: "#",
            cuisineType: ["Sandwiches", "American", "BBQ"],
            description: "Modern, healthy, awesome BBW",
            priceRange: "$",
            userFavorite: 0
        }}                      
    ];
```

And here's my markup.

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantListFromSearch" ng-class="{restaurant.details.userFavorite === 1: favorite}">
                <img src="{{restaurant.details.image}}" alt="{{restaurant.restaurantName}}">

                <div class="details">
                    <a href="{{restaurant.details.url}}">{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</a>
                    <span class="cuisine-type">{{restaurant.details.cuisineType}}</span>
                    <p>{{restaurant.details.description}}</p>
                    <span class="price-rating">{{restaurant.details.priceRange}}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>   
            </li><!-- end restaurant result -->                                                                 
        </ul>
```

Added jsFiddle for readability, doesn't actually work due to missing dependencies (requireJs, etc)

http://jsfiddle.net/HtJDy/

Can anyone point me in the right direction? :}

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ngClass is looking for an angular expression to get evaluated, with "The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values."

For your example to work, its a little opposite of what you think, where the left portion is the class you want to add, and the right side if the boolean expression.

```
<li ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantListFromSearch" ng-class="{ favorite : restaurant.details.userFavorite == 1}">
```

The object map like this allows you to have multiple classes if you so desired:

```
<li ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantListFromSearch" ng-class="{ favorite : restaurant.details.userFavorite == 1, otherClass: otherBooleanExpression }">
```

Also note that the boolean expression isn't quite JavaScript... if you plug in the strict equals '===', you'll get an error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awe, I was so close! This works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: for classes seperated by a "-", put the class names in quotes like 'classname' to avoid syntax errors